# Generating Views Block to list Taxonomy Terms of nodes curently visible in a Views Page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a Views Page which lists nodes of the content type, Article. This page also contains pagination since I configured it to display no more than 6 articles per page.

So for example, if I have 10 articles, 6 of them would be displayed on page 1 and the remaining 4 would be on page 2. In addition, Article has a term reference field called Tags.

I was wondering if it's possible to have a Views block I can attach to my **original View** I mentioned earlier (a list of Article content type) that lists Tags belonging only Articles currently visible on the **original View** on one of the paginated pages.

Going again with my example, I want this Views block to display Tags from the 6 Articles when I'm on page 1. Likewise, I want this block to display Tags from the remaining 4 Articles when I'm on page 2.

Here's a little graphic of what I'm trying to do.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXmwU.png

Also, I'm not sure if this info is relevant but I plan to use the Context module to attach this Views Block to the Views page.

I was thinking along the lines of Contextual Filters but I'm not quite sure what arguments I would use.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand i'm not sure how Context will help you do this ... off the top of my head this solution came to mind.

- In your 1st view make the Tag field a hidden field the view so the View knows about it.
- Use `hook_views_pre_render` to loop through the results (and maybe respect page offset and # of items per page -- you can get that from the `$view` object) and grab your view field Tag values and store them into an array.
- Still in `hook_views_pre_render` you can set `$view->attachment_after = $some_string;` where `$some_string` is like the list of your Tags.

In code it will look something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->current_display == 'VIEW_ID') {
    $tags_on_page = array();
    // $_GET['page'] has page number.
    // $views->items_per_page has items per page count.

    $page_offset = intval($_GET['page']);
    // this is somewhat wasteful, but easier than a loop at the moment.
    $paged_results = array_chunk($view->result, $view->items_per_page, TRUE);

    // Build up the Tag list for X page of the results.
    foreach ($paged_results[$page_offset] as $i => $result) {
      $tags_on_page[] = $result->value; // save the taxonomy term name to the tags list.
    }

    // Take our tags and build a block of HTML to embed after the view.
    // Alternatively, maybe take these tag values and pass them as parameters
    // to a new view we attach after programmatically -- thats more work.

    // if you know the url prefix you've given these taxonomy terms use it here, or use something like entity_uri().
    $num_tags = count($tags_on_page);
    if ($num_tags) {
      for ($i=0;$i<$num_tags; $i++) {
        $term = $tags_on_page[$i];
        $tags_on_page[$i] = l($term, '/URL/ALIAS/BASE/PATH/TO/TERM' . $term);
        // or, ... $term may have a path value already ... I cant remember :).
        // $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($tags_on_page[$i]);
        // $term_path = entity_uri('taxonomy_term', $term[0]);
        // $tags_on_page[$i] = l($term[0]->name, $term_path);
      }
      $links = implode('<br>', $tags_on_page);
      $view->attachment_after = '<div class="myBlockAfterView"><h3>Related Tags</h3>' . $links . '</div>';
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I should really look at attached pics before I start writing code ... now i dont understand if your tiling those results on a page, or those are per-page example boxes ... and my code, probably doesnt do whatever that pic is showing. sigh.

Comment: Haha no worries, Tenken. I still appreciate the input!

As for your inquiry, the explanation gets weird because a "Page" generated through Views can be a collection of pages if Pagination is enabled.

So the block would be a per page basis...but automatically rebuilt since each page would contain different Articles with different tags.